# Protractor: .sendKeys() converting my text to Uppercase

Tags: angular, protractor, sendkeys

When I am sending email through protractor to my page it is converting that to uppercase .

Page.inputs.email.sendKeys('test@abc.com.au');

Can somebody please help me to know the reason why it is happening and how can I correct it.

Thanks

Comment: If text won't convert to uppercase when input manually, check your code did some wrapper on `email`,  like `email` is not `ElementFinder` type but customize type.  Thus it's better to share the relate code of `email`'s definition, init, re-assign value.

Answer (score 0):

First check your caps lock is not enabled when you are testing and try below given code lines.

```
Page.inputs.email.sendKeys(protractor.Key.SHIFT);
Page.inputs.email.sendKeys('test@abc.com.au');
```